# Java Regex - Pattern.match fails to deal with lazy match

Tags: java, regex

This is the sample code

```
String m_testPattern = "AB.*?";
String m_testMatcherString = "ABCDCDCDCD";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(m_testPattern);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(m_testMatcherString);   
if (matcher.matches()) {
    // This means the regex matches
    System.out.println("Successful comparison");

} else {
    // match failed
    System.out.println("Comparison failed !!!");
}
```

Ideally the match operation should result in a failure and give me output as "Comparison failed !!!"

But this code snippet gives me "Successful comparison" as output

I checked online regex tools with the same input and the result was different

I did the trial in this site http://regexr.com/v1/

Here when I put AB.*? in the regex and ABCDCDCDCD as the string to be compared, then the search stops at AB. 
This means the comparison performed is a Lazy Comparison and not a greedy one

Can anyone please explain why the same use case fails in case of Java Pattern.match function ?

My test case is something like
        1. regex AB\wCD should match with ABZCD plus fail at AB2CD 
        2. AB\w{2}CD would match ABZZCD
        3. AB\d{1,3}CD should match AB555CD or AB6CD or AB77CD plus fail at ABCD or AB9999CD etc
        4. AB.* should match AB(followed by anything)
        5. AB.*? should fail if input like ABCDCDCD is given for comparison

```
All the 4 steps is passed successfully  while using matcher.matches() function <br/>
Only the fifth one gives a wrong answer. (5th scenario also gives a success message eventhough it should fail)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `matches()` asserts that **the whole input** matches the regex (the regex is implicitly anchored), which it does, since `*` allows `.` to repeat without limit. Regex testers usually only do something equivalent to `Matcher.find()`, which doesn't anchors the regex, so `.*?` exhibits its laziness and matches an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply
If I use the Matcher.find() method, this use case works as expected., but other simple inputs like normal AB.* fails to match ABCDCDCD

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do here. Do you want to validate, or extract content from some text?

Comment: Sorry If I confused you 
No extraction, only validation in this scenario
I will have an input string (regex) and another string , which I should compare with the regex
Only validation is required

Comment: Can you explain what are the rules for the input to pass the validation?

Comment: @Mparame: Then why do you expect the test case to fail. As Mariano said, what are the validation criteria?

Comment: My test case is something like  
  1. regex AB\wCD should match with ABZCD plus fail at AB2CD  
  2. AB\w{2}CD would match ABZZCD  
  3. AB\d{1,3}CD should match AB555CD or AB6CD or AB77CD plus fail at ABCD or AB9999CD etc  
  4. AB.* should match AB(followed by anything)  
  5. AB.*? should fail if input like ABCDCDCD is given for comparison  
  
 All the 4 steps is passed successfully  while using matcher.matches() function  
 Only the fifth one gives a wrong answer. (5th scenario also gives a success message eventhough it should fail)

Comment: @nhahtdh and  @ Mariano
I have added the scenario as you asked in the main question itself

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense 1) `\w` matches `A-Za-z` and also `0-9` and `_`. 5) Why should it fail, when `.*?` indicates that it is allowed to match 0 **or more**, *lazily*?

Comment: @ nhahtdh 
Sorry I wrongly typed Case 1.   
For case 5,  I will give another example.   Normally  regex like AB\\w*?CD  will match anything like ABxyzCD, but will fail for inputs like ABxyzCDqwe.    But if we give the second input to the above mentioned code, it will give us SUCCESSFUL comparison (instead of failure)

Answer (score -1):

```
matches()
```

return true if the whole string matches the given pattern.

```
find()
```

tries to find a substring that matches the pattern.